# Using SelectLayerByAttribute and Where Clause in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, where-clause

I'm trying to select the minimum value from a field to select and export that one feature to a temp shp so I can copy the field data from the point to a line. So far I have this:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set up the environment
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\BrettM\Desktop\OD_Python_Testing"
env.overwriteOutput = True


# Get Min
fcPoints = r"\OD_Shapefiles\One_Road_Points.shp"
temp = r"\OD_Shapefiles\intersectTempPoint.shp"

arcpy.Statistics_analysis(fcPoints, r"C:\Users\BrettM\Desktop\OD_Python_Testing\table",[["NEAR_DIST", "MIN"]])
nearIntersect = r"C:\Users\BrettM\Desktop\OD_Python_Testing\table"
minDistCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("table", ["MIN_NEAR_DIST"])
for row in minDistCursor:
    intersectDist = row[0]

print intersectDist

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fcPoints, "fcPoints_Lyr")
print "one"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("fcPoints_Lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", ' "NEAR_DIST" = intersectDist ')
print "two"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fcPoints_Lyr, "\OD_Scratch\\temp")
print "three"

del row
del minDistCursor
```

All those print statements are just to see where I get in the script.  I get to print one.
I can't figure out how to get the where clause to work for the selectlayerbyattribute.  I keep getting an invalid expression error.  I may have the copyfeatures wrong as well but I haven't gotten to that part yet.

The overall goal is to cycle through a line file, select points that intersect that line and copy the data from the point that is nearest to a centerline to the line.  I'm using near to get the distance from the centerline for all the points and will work on adding the rest once I get this part to work.

There may be a much easier way to go about this but I'm very new to Python so I'm learning on the fly.

Comment: Thanks Ken, that fixed that problem.  Now I get to "two", now to figure out how to get to "three"! When I have more time I'll have to look into the why of needing it that way.

Comment: And all the way to "three"! Now for the next part, thanks for the help Ken.

Comment: Hey Brett, I added an explanation about the formatting of the where clause to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is in the where clause of the SelectByAttribute tool.

You can try: `"\"NEAR_DIST\" = {0}".format(intersectDist)` in the where clause part in the SeletByAttributeTool.

The field name needs to be in quotes but the value for intersectDist doesn't since it's a number. The entire statement also needs to be in quotes. To make sure Python doesn't terminate the string at the second and third quotes, you need to use `\"` to tell Python to treat that quote as part of the string. To avoid using a lot of " and + to string togehter the where clause, you can use the `.format(variable_or_value)` function to substitute in a number where the `{}` is. If you had multiple values you want to substitute in, you can have many `{}` and many values. For example:

```
"{0} {1}".format('Hi', 'Brett')
```

will return the string "Hi Brett".

The numbers in the `{}` are necessary for Python 2.6.x. If you are on Python 2.7.x, you don't need the numbers.

Comment: good explanation, and just to point out that if you use the index numbers in the string formatting, you can reuse the arguments: `"{0} {1} {0}".format('Hi', 'Brett')` returns "Hi Brett Hi".

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanation.  I've got 2 books and been all over the internet and you just explained what I was trying to find in a few sentences.  mr.adam too.